# IQueryable left outer join linq extension

Tags: c#, linq

I wanted to create an extension method to enable left outer joins in linq/lambda IQueryables, and I have come up with the following, but I am still not sure it's completely correct.

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
    IQueryable<TInner> inner,
    Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return outer.GroupJoin(
        inner,
        outerKeySelector,
        innerKeySelector,
        (o, i) => new { outer = o, innerCollection = i })
    .SelectMany(
        a => a.innerCollection.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (a, i)=>resultSelector(a.outer,i));
}
```

I am especially concerned with the `resultSelector` being a `Func`, not an `Expression`, but I cant call an `Expression` in the lambda on the last line. I assume it gets cast automatically, but it's only an assumption.

**Is this correct? How can I improve this? Can it be optimized more?**

Comment: Have tested it? Does it generate a left outer join sql?

Comment: I've tested it on AsQueriable collections, unfortunately haven't yet had the opportunity to test it on an actual database

Comment: If you didn't actually test it, how would you know if the improvements are improvements at all?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is way more complex than that, since Funcs<> cant't be translated to the database, so you'll have to "call" the expression. But since you can't call a expression, you'll have to change the expression into another that means what you need it to means.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615693/extension-method-for-iqueryable-left-outer-join-using-linq) on StackOverflow. It has an good explanation on Linq inner workings and the accepted answer has a method that do the outer join. Be sure to read the second answer too, since it shows some issues that arise on more complex queries. And just as a warning, the method you are trying to write will easily gets 150 lines long (that's why I didn't copied it here)...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what i was worried about. I will do some more reading on your link.